# facebook leads retrieval issue using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Getting the following error while retrieving leads through graph api using form id. The same end point works fine for other users, but its not working for one of the users of the app. Not sure why its happening. Is there anything related to account type on facebook?

(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.

https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<form_id>/leads?access_token=<>&appsecret_proof=<>

Comment: Have you first of all verified, that this user actually granted your app the permission in question?

Comment: And what role does the user have on the page?

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

After adding pages_read_engagement in the scope list and making the user reauthorize the app the said api call is working fine but my query is why did it work for others.
The user does not have any role. User is following oAuth to permit the app to access his facebook pages and ad data